# Indentation lines in algorithm package

Tags: algorithm2e, algorithmic

I am using the algpseudocode and the `algorithm2e` package, and want the lines down below the indents like below (the example on the algorithm [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Algorithms#Typesetting_using_the_algorithm2e_package)).
Does anyone know how to achieve this easily?

[image: img]